# Alternating stripes with vega

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, vega

How can we add alternating grid lines or stripes with vega?

Suppose we start with this example:

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/grouped-bar-chart/

Here it is in the editor:

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/grouped-bar-chart

This is what it looks like:

[image: bar plot]

How can we change the figure, so that we have alternating horizontal stripes in the background for A and C, but not B?

In other words, what if we want to display a gray background stripe for "A" and "C", but a white stripe for "B".

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **marks** *group*:

```
{
  "type": "group",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data_category",
      "source": "table",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["category"],
          "fields": ["category"],
          "ops": ["count"]
        },
        {"type": "identifier", "as": "category_id"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "category_background",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "data_category"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "category"},
          "height": {"scale": "yscale", "band": 1},
          "width": {"signal": "width"},
          "fill": {
            "signal": "datum['category_id'] % 2 == 0 ? '#eee' : '#ccc'"
          },
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.6}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

References

*Group Mark*:
https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/group/

*Identifier transform*:
https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/identifier/

[**Open in Vega Editor**](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJBBpRtZRWwY44s3UkXbYNzNrgAPJAhwAbOJWkgA7jSy9GgAzAAMYTLwNGRYaABMACyRIDhIsrI04mRoAjKySJgoqADaoOJucGggRUxevsRIHgwKaGUgUIXkbIoAntWavjhsBmoSaCmNzVWoYZQAjAC+UqCdmN19A0MjdOpo8zJTLROUAGzLq11kPf1a26N7qPGHTcezlACcFx1XN1sywwe41QIRe0xOiW+aw2txAACF7rtgZNXjM5gB2KG-TboBEAnZjDQHEBHNGUeJY9bXHHwxGEhJgt7zBaUmHVPGpAmPUEk1EnAAcrOpsIAwnTHijwe9zisflS-ugxfigUTGWSlrLocLqkrOSqGbypXMKZrsaLxcCeaSTpiALqLW0yaBNVqlcqVaq9Z31GSYXoWap6cSyXyyNjILJoUAFIrVWo+kAAMxocA8IfQWr+yxAiiQ2RmGDgMTiAPSmWyJxN7oQBec3qqvv9BY8WTgNlD4aQkdQ0cKxRqSDqDaTKbT1Wt2dz+eqASCMF8pgYwbQmEULRkAC84KYV2u4DJxIYZquWt8KjXqlA2B4er4-QH0D1y00OxGNL3Y+h48Pk6n03qkUkSc8zIGZQC4RAC0zPp4jCEBFgdGQkGcV12h6FNxEwaovETLCnU6ep0C9AjhzUKAAGsAGUaC3CYZA8QdUwABTLLIclQRJNyyeRnH2b50LgTDAzYbBw18etqjrEj4MdEBkEUciIDaUB7wLEwzBwUM+2UkBzwLGMkAAfWg-onTMRQoALb87ynCBEx6BAdNU6okDIEw+HWXx1PMJhbhKOU2Vk380yU0oAu1WS2DwNoOjMIT7VlZz0ECQS1F-RRfH0S8zUMwIZMQuSbEUnS9Oy+U+kMvQKO85dGwfHM4CgPCk1MRyezkbT0AM4yzXgmRBKveQoxAVLt2G25wOkoiJJkYL-xMvrC2LLD2ok6bpJkIN0w1fxAmCVaYgqDwZz2+ds2TDxjoOsgjuqGMGAQEoAHITNy2QnttbQAFJtHibQAF5-u0MJtAAfm0J6AGI4Bhp7tFQCHIagZGnsWi6PAAeTSKA6Amw03jmc4EIdb4kpAbzNNm1rhsTJBLJWj9+2sg8PXQWn6a8xccF8sq2QQ-rxEGsCRswsb2rxtaQGIl1fDm3ntWJp1DqaUL2lK9BoliZrzBjAsttnegAAonulrwnoAShk-CXVV6sC0BO8m0DPMQxkKdQOqTWSzkTtu0Z6p2bgZq5fQQFAPggr5OKt1dNZkA9EUJSqbE9qDIDumg8WsnFEa5qBrYIb2tGjLxeGyWHdm0d-zD+lsy9hmQHLkZfC2viZF41appAKSZcrv9xz5bNnHiMuu57hNrVmc6aEu0eZYza9bz7sdQ65cZidJp2vxcYPqdTzr45sJTs3zwvQGL4aO9AEPu5HmQ2ETRMIEz1AAFoBGzPGb9MkAH6fl-r5V09kWLWvgEAMA8CtOYH9p6zxjusCAK1YqYVzIg42fgYB0DgE9KQ2h7oIEoOjc22gAB8dgJCrn0JgY2dQ6bkRwXgwoD1CEzw8JbNUM5MGeW+JPeODEKJWxAE0Q6w1eHKFAdmPQz8WziGFrwhAgRZD1GzOsZwDcb74MoBOYm9p7RAA)

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution! I continued editing your example in Vega Editor and ended up creating an additional yscale with different padding for the alternating bands: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/21b7b4615c2e4c39a01c618be3f2ca84/spec.json